# Angular 2 subscribe not working

Tags: angular, subscribe

For reasons beyond the scope of this question, I have had to stop using `@injectable`. I converted my services that use it, just manually newing them up rather than using `@injectable` and it works for all services except for my service that uses `subscribe` My service that uses subscribe did work before I had to remove `@injectable`. Can I get it to work without `@injectable`?.

Code:

Service:

```
import { Subject } from 'rxjs/Subject';

export class ResultSelectionService {
  // Observable string sources
  private resultSelectedSource = new Subject();
  // Observable string streams
  resultSelected$ = this.resultSelectedSource.asObservable();
  // Service message commands
  selectResult(result: any, place: any) {
    this.resultSelectedSource.next({result: result, place: place});
  }
}
```

service user (the selectResult function does execute - Good):

```
//arrow function because when called above "this" is an html element
resultClick = (event) => {
    this.resultSelectionService.selectResult(event.data.result, event.data.place);
}
```

method that should execute but does not ( code never gets inside `result => {`:

```
constructor( ) {
this.resultSelectionService = new ResultSelectionService();
    this.resultSelectionService.resultSelected$.subscribe(
        result => {

            this.selectedResult = { result };

            $('#result-details-modal').appendTo("body").modal('show');

            $('#result-details-modal').on('shown.bs.modal', (e) => {
                this.resizeMap();
                this.canGetAddress = true;
                this.addMarkersToMap(this.map);
                //this.bindAutoCompleteToMap();
            })
            console.log(this.selectedResult.result);
        });
}
```

Can I get the subscribed function to execute without using `@injectable`? If not, how can I work around this, creating something similar?

Comment: These to things are entirely unrelated. You should rather try to get your setup fixed. `@Injectable()` is not known to cause any issues.

Comment: The relationship between the caller of `selectResult` and the caller of `resultSelected$.subscribe` is not made at all clear in your question. Are they in the same component? Your statement that you've had to stop using `@Injectable` is concerning and suggests the problem is elsewhere.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer What do you suggest I do to get my setup fixed? I have tried your only suggestion

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer Since I managed to get this working I have discovered that some of my other services in my app that I did not stop using `@injectable` for actually do work, meaning that nothing is wrong with my setup or with `@injectable`. Something is just wrong with my providers. I have updated my other question. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you need here is a single instance of `ResultSelectionService`, that's why your subscribe method is never called.

You need to add `@Injectable()` on `ResultSelectionService`, add it in your `forRoot()` module method (or directly in `AppModule`'s providers if it's the only module you have) and use it like that:

```
constructor( private resultSelectionService:ResultSelectionService ) {
    this.resultSelectionService.resultSelected$.subscribe(
        result => {

            this.selectedResult = { result };

            $('#result-details-modal').appendTo("body").modal('show');

            $('#result-details-modal').on('shown.bs.modal', (e) => {
                this.resizeMap();
                this.canGetAddress = true;
                this.addMarkersToMap(this.map);
                //this.bindAutoCompleteToMap();
            })
            console.log(this.selectedResult.result);
        });
}
```

This way, you'll be sure that only one instance of your `ResultSelectionService` is provided everywhere in your app, and you'll be able to trigger the observable from anywhere.